# Xslt 1.0, change date format

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

As I can change date format, the value comes from an xml its format is "yyyy-mm-dd" and I want to change it to "dd-mm-yyyy" I am using a version of xslt 1.0

This is xml

```html
<Valores>

  <Valor calificacion="1" fecha="2014-07-31" moneda="1" fechaPagoCuota="2014-06-10" diasMora="0" cuotasMora="0" cuota="4736000.0" disponible="-1" saldoMora="0.0" saldoActual="599999000.0" cuotasCanceladas="1" valorInicial="600000000.0" totalCuotas="1" periodicidad="4"
  />

</Valores>
```

This is Xslt

```html
<td align="center" class="Estilo2">
  <xsl:value-of select="Valores/Valor/@fechaPagoCuota" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring()` and `concat()`.

Example...

```
<td align="center" class="Estilo2">
  <xsl:variable name="dt" select="Valores/Valor/@fechaPagoCuota"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
    substring($dt,9,2),'-',
    substring($dt,6,2),'-',
    substring($dt,1,4))" />
</td>
```

Note: Using a variable is not necessary; I only used it to make the concat easier to read.